# user defined thread library constructor getting invoked only once

Tags: c++, multithreading, schedule

I created my own thread library... Of course its a simple **non-preemptive** library in which the threads are executed in the order they are invoked. The brief out line of the program is as follows:

```
class Thread
{
static Thread sched;
/*called only once*/
static void init()
{
*create a context for sched thread* 
static void schedule()
{ 
....
setcontext(current thread from the queue);
return if empty
}
Thread(function)
{
intializes the context via getcontext and sets the uc_link to the context of sched
and pushed into the queue and calls schedule function
}
```

Every thing seems to be fine with single thread. But when i initialize two thread objects only one of them is executing. 
I doubt that when the first thread completes its job, it returns to the schedule function and when the schedule function sees the queue is empty... it also returns.

But I observe that the constructor is called only once for the first thread!! Why is that so?

If i don't call the schedule function from the constuctor, instead i define a function like

```
void start()
{
 schedule();
}
```

and call it after all the threads are initialized it was executing correctly. But i dont want to use this method..

please explain me the path of execution and the solution to the above problem.
Here's the actual code for it

```
class thread
{

static queue<thread> Q;



    ucontext_t con;
    int u_p;
    int c_p;
static void init()
{
    flag=0;
    getcontext(&schd.con);
    //cout<<"fgh\n";
    schd.con.uc_link=0;
    schd.con.uc_stack.ss_sp=malloc(ST_S);
    schd.con.uc_stack.ss_size=ST_S;
    makecontext(&schd.con, schd.schedule, 0);

}
static thread main, schd;
static int flag;
public:

thread()
    {   }   
thread(int i){ init(); }

    static  void schedule()
    {
        //cout<<"ii\n";
        if(Q.empty()){
        flag=0;
        return;
        }
            main=Q.front();
            Q.pop();
            setcontext(&main.con);
    init();
    //cout<<"yea\n";    

    }   

    thread(void (*fn)(), int u_p=15)
    {

        getcontext(&con);
        con.uc_link=&schd.con;
        con.uc_stack.ss_sp=malloc(ST_S);  
        con.uc_stack.ss_flags=0;        
        con.uc_stack.ss_size=ST_S;
        makecontext(&con, fn, 0);
        //cout<<"hjkl\n";
        Q.push(*this);
    if(flag==0){
    flag=1;
    schedule();
    }           
    }
static void start(){ schedule(); }

    };
queue<thread> thread::Q;
thread thread::main;
thread thread::schd;
int thread::flag;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is happening:

1. you create a new thread
2. `Thread::Thread()` calls `Thread::shedule()`
3. `Thread::shedule()` calls `setcontext()`
4. control flow switches to `function` of new `Thread` object
5. this new thread executes, not switching back to its parent context, so another thread cannot be created

I think all thread libraries and OS API's I have seen either create threads suspended or provide a flag to create threads in suspended state. So it's a good way to go, otherwise you lose stop current thread at the moment of creating another one. Moreover, since you use lightweight threads, you're almost forced to create threads suspended without any flag in order to be able to create multiple threads from the main one.

Comment: After the 5th step the thread returns back to schedule actually!!! because i kept the **UC-link** of the created thread pointing towards the schedule function( i have mentioned that in my Question ) ... Once  u see that...

Comment: @nitish712 I see that, but it seems not going back. Did you try adding some printing after that `setcontext()` line or debugging it? So we can be sure it reaches that point.

Comment: Yea, you are right!! that thread was not returning to the calling function. I doubt that the context of sched was already executed( the schedule function) and hence it is not returning... But atleast it should print something after that ryt? Why is that not happening??

Comment: @nitish712 Well it shouldn't return back itself. It may exit program if it doesn't reach call of `setcontext()` of main thread. Or there could be an error with saving/restoring context, which is hidden by other use case. Since code is rather general, I can only guess about the reason. Are you trying to save context during creation of thread and return back to main thread? If so, look close which contexts are saved and restored.

Comment: One more doubt is that suppose the first thread is executing... then i call the constructor for the 2nd thread.. where does this function execute?? Plz reply...

Comment: @nitish712 It should execute in the context of the first thread. So as I said pay attention to context switching. You probably want to pass a pointer to parent thread into new thread during its creation.